# No output from egrep through PHP exec

Tags: php, grep, exec

I am running the below command from php command line.

```
<?php $out = exec('cat file.txt | egrep -i "string"');
echo $out; ?>
```

I executed the same command directly to the shell worked perfectly. But when I run the php it doesnt show any output. What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Try using the `$output` argument since the return value will only contain the last line from the program: `$output = array(); $result = exec('cat file.txt | egrep -i "string"', $output); print_r($output); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably that you have not bothered [reading the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#refsect1-function.exec-returnvalues) (emphasis by me):

> Return Values
>
> **The last line from the result** of the command. If you need to [...] **have all the data from the command** [...] use the passthru() function.
>
> **To get the output [...] use the output parameter.**

In other words, you should either set the `$output` parameter (the second parameter), or look into using the [`passthru()`](http://php.net/passthru) function.

Comment: He should also be able to use `exec` as long as he make use of the second argument `$output`.